# yii2: How can I configure Url manager when using module and GET parameters?

Tags: yii2

I am trying to configure Url's in my modules but I am getting a 404 error on accessing the following Url's. This is my products page url example:

```
http://localhost/jambomall/web/products/products/details-product?deal_key=nvx3FtQf&url_title=3-Jojo-Cat-ponted-heels
```

I want the Url manager to show this:

```
http://localhost/jambomall/web/products/details-product/nvx3FtQf/3-Jojo-Cat-ponted-heels
```

How can I configure my Url manager to display this? This is not working for me.

```
'products/<deal_key:\w+>/<url_title:\w+>' => 'products/products/details-products'
```

Here is my web.php

```
        'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [
            'products/<deal_key:\w+>/<url_title:\w+>' => 'products/products/details-product',
        ],
    ],
```

and my `.htaccess` that is in my web folder

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

your .htaccess seems OK. see the below configuration. This may work for you.

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => array(
         '' => 'site/index',
         'module/<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
         '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
         '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
         '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
],
```

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand the configurations well. Could you write your example according to my example?

Comment: forget other things just add `'module/<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You add below code in `web.php` file...

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
 ],
```

And add `.htaccess` file in `web` folder for below code....

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```